# cPanel backup stay too much in progress, then it timeout

Tags: cpanel

I'm trying to do a backup, it stay a lot in progress, and after few hours, it say timeout, without any other errors. What should i do here? I asked for more memory, more rams.
Still same problem

Answer (score 0):

The question would have needed more details for a proper answer. However, I am assuming that you are trying to generate backup using "cpanel default backup" option from a cPanel user account.

The timeout can be due to following reasons :

- Your datasize is high and the process of backup dies as per the host node limitation (by host node I mean the main server where WHM is installed, and you are a single user on it)
- Server's I/O is busy to generate backup.

If you are facing the issue on a hosting company server then raise a ticket so that you know if there is any limits applied by them. 
If its your own server, check the server usage as time of backup and login into the shell to see if backup file is getting generated or not.

You can add more information for us to pinpoint our answer.